# How to convert XYZ to from-to format with azimuth and dip information?

Tags: coordinate-system, data, coordinates, convert, geometry-conversion

I have an Excel spreadsheet with header, survey, and assay drill data.

Header data contains hole ID, location coordinates, and length.
Survey data contains related downhole survey with distance, azimuth and dip values.
Assay data contains related location coordinates and %s.

Since I know the coordinates, azimuth, and dip, I would like to be able to convert the assay table to from-to format. Does anyone have a function / procedure / example?

Header data:

[image]

Survey data:

[image]

Assay data:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  GIS SE is less a place where tutorials are located, and more a place to go where, when you run the tutorial and it produces unexpected results, you can share your procedure and focused problem to get problem-solving assistance. Questions here are expected to show effort toward solving the task, and if code is involved, the code should be included.

Comment: Didn't say which software are you going to use with this ?